# Use of the adjective "this" before a person's name to indicate contempt

Tags: usage

Occasionally one hears the demonstrative adjective "this" directly preceding an individual's name to imply a pejorative or dimunitive connotation.  E.g., "Who is this...this *Murphy* to assume such airs." It is obviously some form of objectification, but I haven't succeeded in finding anything in writing discussing the usage.

Answer (score 0):

It's a recognisable use by English speakers. The pejorative connotation is not just implied by the word 'this' as by the way the name is spoken and the pause (which isn't always there, but you noted it, and it is often there for dramatic effect).

Asking "*who is this Murphy*" acknowledges the name of a person, but the determiner strips them somewhat of their individuality. A determiner suggests that their name alone is not enough to identify them. It is somewhat similar to when people refer to a random person as "*some guy*" instead "*a man*".

When you use someone's name it is an acknowledgement that you are aware of them as individual. For example, if someone asked "*who is Murphy*?" it would be clear they have become aware of a specific individual called Paul but want to know more about them. By contrast, asking a question like "*who is this man?*" means you either don't know their name *or are not acknowledging it*. "*Who is this Murphy*"is something of a halfway point between these two.

The pause that you included is something of a dramatic trope - it further suggests that the speaker has forgotten the person's name, or perhaps that it is beneath them to remember it.

Comment: In British conversation, 'that _person's name_' is just as insulting, if not more so.